# C# Entity Framework - How can I get a column which is specified as a paremeter

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I was writing a method in C# using ADO.NET Entity Framework for MySQL. I was making a function where when the function is called, I specify the column I'm selecting, kind of like this:

```
public string GetColumn(string whereValue, string column)
{
  xxxEntities data = new xxxEntities();
  lock (lockObject)
  {
    var result = data.employees.SqlQuery("SELECT `" + column + "` FROM `employees` WHERE `Code` = '" + code + "'");
    return result.ToListAsync().Result[0].????; // I want to get the column in the parameters
  }
}
```

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to return a single column, not a list of `employee` objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that your target column is a string, for a moment.  Then your syntax would be this:

```
// I've parameterized the parameterizable part of your query
var result = data
   .employees
   .SqlQuery<string>("SELECT `" + column + "` FROM `employees` WHERE `Code` = @p0", code); 
return result.ToListAsync().Result[0]; // Result[0] is a string
```

If your target column were an integer, that first line would be:

```
var result = data
    .employees
    .SqlQuery<int>("SELECT `" + column + "` FROM `employees` WHERE `Code` = @p0", code);
```

The program will have no idea what type `result` needs to be, so you need to tell it by supplying a type parameter to the `SqlQuery` method.

If `column` can have varying types, you have a bit of a problem, because there is no way for C# to intuit what the property type is going to be.  You might have to use some special logic.

Another way to do this, by the way, that doesn't involve building custom SQL, would be to use the `employee` object for querying, but use Reflection to access the desired property:

```
// Warning:  this is being done from memory. 
var result = data.employees
     .Where(e => Code == code);
// Assuming the property is a string:
return result
     .Select(e => (string) typeof(employee).GetProperty(column).GetValue(e))
     .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: After I wrote this, I thought of another way, involving passing a property expression to your method that would tell LINQ what property of `employee` you want. That would be faster than Reflection would be.  Let me know if you'd like more information.